# LogCat won't show my logs

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I've searched for similar problems, but I didn't find anything useful - I'm working with `eclipse`, and I can't see my Logs.
The device is connected properly, the app runs and does what it's supposed to do, but I get no logs from it.
I get other logs messages from the device, not the ones that I print, e.g. `Log.d("SMS", "hello")`. On the other hand, if I use the statement `System.out.println("hello")`, I do see it, tagged as `System.out`.
I've tried to disconnect and reconnect the device, restart it, close and open `eclipse`, choose the device from `Device` window. It happens both with a 'real' device and an emulator. I've also tried to remove the filtering, but nothing helps - I still don't get the logs.

Comment: When you remove the filtering does it show any logs at all?
What happens when you open a terminal and exec "adb logcat"?

Comment: @davidgiga1993 As I wrote, when I remove the filtering I see all the logs, except the logs that I write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've found the problem -
Apprently there are some illegal tags, and I've used one of them.
My app is spam SMS blocker, and I've used the tag `SMS`. If I change it to another tag (like SMSBlocker) it suddenly appears in the `LogCat`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project is using proguard.
Basically proguard will remove all the debug logs and optimize your code while creating apk.

Try adding `proguard.enabled=false` in your `project.properties`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I've also tried to change the log level to `i`, and it still won't print it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use TAG.

When you log from your android app, the first parameter is a TAG string. So if you set it up to a unique string (like your app name) then you can later filter by it in Eclipse.

```
Example : Log.e(TAG, "state error");
```

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in my question, I do use a tag - `Log.d("myApp", "hello")`. The tag is "myApp".