# Missing logcat messages

Tags: android, logging

I have two classes, `A1` and `A2`.  Both inherit from `BaseActivity`, which, in turn, inherits from `AppCompatActivity`.

`BaseActivity` has a boatload of logging statements that track, e.g., activity lifecycle methods.  Like this: `Log.d(tag, "in onCreate");`

Those messages are logged, as expected, from `A1` but ***not from `A2`***!  I've tried monitoring logcat both from AS and from command line.  I can repeat the problem on several Android emulators and in a couple of dev environments.

If I simply replace, e.g., `Log.d(tag, "in onCreate")` with `System.out.println(tag + ": in onCreate")`, all of the expected messages appear.

Totally mystified, at this point.  Anybody got any suggestions about where my log messages are going?

**Edited to add:**

I have replaced all calls to `Log.d` with calls to the following method:

```
private void log(String message) {
    Log.d("LOGGER", tag);
    Log.d(tag, message);
    System.out.println(tag + ": " + message);
}
```

Here is sample output from the two subclasses:

```
07-09 10:26:42.036 9657-9657/net.callmeike.android.latest D/LOGGER: A1
07-09 10:26:42.036 9657-9657/net.callmeike.android.latest D/A1: in onCreate
07-09 10:26:42.036 9657-9657/net.callmeike.android.latest I/System.out: A1: in onCreate

07-09 10:27:10.837 9657-9657/net.callmeike.android.latest D/LOGGER: A2
07-09 10:27:10.837 9657-9657/net.callmeike.android.latest I/System.out: A2: in onCreate
```

It appears that the variable `tag` is, in fact, the thing that drives the issue.  Anybody understand why?

FWIW:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".A1"
        android:label="@string/a1_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".A2"
        android:label="@string/a2_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**EDITED to add**: Sources for the three Activity-related classes:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String tag;
    private final int layout;

    public BaseActivity(String tag, int layout) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    protected abstract void test();

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(tag, "in onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout);

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(this::makeSnackbar);
    }

    final void makeSnackbar(View v) {
        Snackbar.make(v, R.string.action_test, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(R.string.action_test, v1 -> test())
            .show();
    }

    // blah blah blah
}

// BaseActivity logs show up in logcat
public class A1 extends BaseActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "A1";

    public A1() {
        super(TAG, R.layout.activity_a1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void test() {
        // blah blah blah
    }
}

// BaseActivity logs do not show up in logcat
public class A2 extends BaseActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "A2";

    public A2() {
        super(TAG, R.layout.activity_a2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void test() {
        // blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your java src to show how you define the classes `A1` and `A2`?

Comment: Sure!  I totally hope it helps!

Comment: You shouldn't implement constructors on your Activities...

Comment: Try `protected abstract String getTag();` and `protected abstract int getLayout();`

Comment: @cricket_007 That sound like a pretty wild guess.  Can you support it in any way?

Comment: Android uses reflection when creating an Activity so having no constructor is the ideal thing specially when the Android OS decides to recreate the activity.

Comment: It's an educated guess that your subclass's tags are not being used therefore you only see "one" type of logging

Comment: to find out if @cricket_007 hypothesis is corect: does the layout assingnment work as expected? what do you get if you log as `Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in onCreate");` does `A2.onCreate()` calll `super.onCreate()` ?

Comment: @Enzokie There is no such thing as "no constructor" in Java.

Comment: @k3b If I do as you suggest, all logging messages will have the tag "BasicActivity", of course.  Also, neither A1 nor A2 override `onCreate`, as you can see from the code.

Comment: @cricket_007 Got it.  Thanks for the guess.  It is not correct, though.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Thanks for the correction, what I mean is a Default Constructor.

Comment: Actually, getClass returns the current class,always. Not the super class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass

Comment: bam!  You are totally correct.  Just tried it. I get messages tagged "A1" and none tagged "A2".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a similar issue - some of my log messages were not shown by the `Log` command.
I've found out that there are some "illegal" tags that the logcat won't show.
In my case it was "SMS" tag. Try to change the bad tags with other ones.
You can take a look here - [LogCat won't show my logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313274/logcat-wont-show-my-logs).
I've searched the documentation, but could not find any list of "illegal" tags.

Comment: Congrats, @TDG.  That is, apparently it.  I mean WTF?  There are some things that you just can't get the Logger to say?  Good grief.  Here's a thought: In addition to "SMS", it won't log "AT".  I wonder if there is some security risk in allowing logging modem command?  Many thanks.  This was driving me crazy.